# Django custom .mo filenames not working for translations?

Tags: django, translation, ngx-translate

I have been playing with django app translation for a while now.

But as my main app is becoming more complex, I've seen that some of the strings are not anymore detected by "makemessages", probaly as they originate from lists, and are only translated in the template through a `{% trans my_list_item %}` tag

That means that each time I'm making a `makemessages`, those msgids are not detected, so the `django.po` file is updated, and my "undetected translations" are commented out.

Ok, I can live with it.
My next move is to create a separate po file `undetected_messages.po` where I stick all the translations which remain undetected.

But the translations are not happening ... even if the corresponding `undetected_messages.mo` file seems to be created ok, and seems to contain the right info.

When I put the undetected translation in the `django.po` file, everthing seems to happen as expected. But not when they are in a different po file with custom namefile.

Any idea why?
Any idea how I could solve the issue?

Subsidiary question: Any idea how I could keep the translations linked to the "admin" module of each app in a separate file ... to avoid having those translations mixed with the ones linked to the "user-exposed" part of the application?

Comment: OK, no answers so far. I've been exploring the django code to see where the limitation to ´django.mo´ files was happening. It seems that ´"currently makemessages only supports domains 'django' and 'djangojs'"´. And it is embedded quite deep into Django code. so no chance to change any of that behavior. I'll then work on getting my untranslated messages easily detectable by ´makemessages´ following advices from https://cfpb.github.io/consumerfinance.gov/translation/#troubleshooting